# (Chart.js) how can I set min value(and max value if I can) as a specific number?

Tags: javascript, chart.js3

I am looking for the way to reach minimum value of the chart.
I found and tried `options.scales.yAxes[n].ticks.beginAtZero = true` but 0 is too small to be a minimum value of my chart.
is there any way to set minimum value of the chart in Object(or using Method)?

Answer (score 1):

From your sample `options`, it seems you're using Chart.js v2 but not v3 as the tag [chart.js3](/questions/tagged/chart.js3) suggests.

Therefore, you can use `options.scales.yAxes[n].ticks.min`

> From [Chart.js v2.9.4 documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/axes/cartesian/#tick-configuration):
>
> `min`: User defined minimum value for the scale, overrides minimum value from data.

The same could be achieved with Chart.js v3 by defining `options.scales.y.min` as explained [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/#common-configuration).

Comment: thank you for your answer. I tried options.scales.y.min just now but it didnt work. i think my version is not 3. and options.scales.yAxes[n].ticks.min is so good.